# Symfony Console : Confused about services

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am using Symfony Console as standalone to create a CLI app.

The Symfony Console documentation is clear as mud when it comes to services.  Could someone please give me a practical example of how it works ?

For example, in the docs you have :

- ["How to call other commands"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html) But this has a comment *"calling a command from code that is not executed on the command line is not a good idea"*
- ["Getting services from the service container"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container) But this doesn't tell you much about how to create them.

I'm really confused !

For example, the  example in "Getting services from the services container" shows an example `$this->userManager->create($input->getArgument('username'));`

But it doesn't show me. how to create this magical `userManager` class that has a `create` function ?

If I create `userManager` as a standard command then I don't see how I can create the sub-functions given that Symfony Console only has three lifecycles ? `initialize()`, `interact()` and `execute()`

Comment: Sure, `$this->userManager = $userManager;` but I'm talking about the `->create()` bit which the `UserManager` "service" provides ?  I don't see how that fits in within the Symfony Console lifecycles and the documentation doesn't provide any practical examples.

Comment: @LittleCode the `UserManager` is a class that is supposed to exist, and supposedly has a `create` method.. You can imagine to substitute UserManager for your own class that you registered as a service with symfony's service container.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using console commands within the Symfony framework or are you using the console component standalone?  Your question indicates it is a standalone command.  In which case the container (and it's services) are not available.

Comment: @Cerad just the standalone (`php composer.phar require symfony/console`)

Comment: Okay.  You are looking at how to use the console command within the framework docs.  You need to look at the standalone docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html You won't see any mention of the container and services in there since the container component is not even loaded let alone configured.  It is possible to install the container but your best bet might be to just use the framework skeleton until you get comfortable.  The skeleton gives you the container, the console and some configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the idea is, that your `Command` describes which services it will use in it's constructor, so if you only want a `UserManager` it would look something like this:

```php
class MyCommand extends Command
{
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManager $userManager)
    {
        // Make sure to call the parent constructor
        parent::__construct(null);

        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Symfony Console does not say anything about the creation of the service, because that is not its responsibility, this is what the [Service Container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) (which is part of the Dependency Injection component) is for in a typical Symfony application and you can use it as well, but possibly in your small CLI Tool it can be overkill.

## The easy way

In you `bin/console.php` (or its equivalent) you can instantiate all services when adding the command like this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();

$userManager = new UserManager(...);
$application->add(new MyCommand($userManager));

$application->run();
```

## Less easy approach

As you can imagine this can become quite tedious and annoying especially if you need different configurations. You can use the service container standalone and make it read the service configuration (basically a representation of the whole stuff between `$app = new Application()` and `$app->run()`:

```php
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

$loader = new YamlFileLoader($containerBuilder, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load('config.yaml');

// ...
$containerBuilder->compile();
```

See docs for [Compiling container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html).

## Alternative approach

If you like to keep the code for creating all those services and don't want a container you can create Factory-classes instead, that create your UserManager (when its needed, instead of creating all services upfront):

```php
$application = new Application();

$userManagerFactory = new UserManagerFactory() ;
$application->add($userManagerFactory->createUserManager());

$application->run();
```

You could also use other containers instead of Symfony's Container if you think configuring and compiling it is too much work. There is for example a very lightweight array based solution called Pimple which might be better suited for your use case or you can use one of the many other libs out there.

## tl;dr

Creating services is not the responsibility of the Console component, hence it's not explained. There are many different approaches with different pros/cons, e.g. instantiating services only when needed vs. configuration required to get a container (or container-like thing to hold your services).